# What is the syntax for a nginx url rewrite

Tags: nginx

I have an app running at

```
http://localhost/subfolder/myapp/
```

How do I create a rewrite rule so that the following urls get redirected to my app?

```
http://localhost/subfolder/myapp/route1
http://localhost/subfolder/myapp/route2
http://localhost/subfolder/myapp/routeN
...anyother routes after http://localhost/subfolder/myapp/
```

Answer (score 0):

add this block nginx rules

```
location ~ /subfolder/myapp/.* {
  redirect from here
}
```

Comment: The server won't start with this.  (I have zero experience of ngnix at this point)

Answer (score 0):

In Nginx you can do rewrites with a `return` inside your server block:

```
location ~ /subfolder/myapp/route(.*) {
    return 301 http://localhost/subfolder/myapp;
}
```

Comment: I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: I tried this `location ~ /subfolder/myapp/.* {
    return 301 http://localhost/subfolder/myapp$request_uri;
}`
and this `location ~ /subfolder/myapp/.* {
    return 301 http://localhost/subfolder/myapp;
}`

Comment: @techguy2000 Ok I edited the question. Just remove the `$request_uri`. This will however discard anything after the url. For example if you call: `http://localhost/subfolder/myapp/route2/test` it will redirect to `http://localhost/subfolder/myapp` without passing `test`.

Comment: I am still getting too many redirects.  Please note my /route(.*) could be anything.  This is what I tried 'location ~ /subfolder/myapp/(.*) {
    return 301 http://localhost/subfolder/myapp;
  }'

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
rewrite ^/subfolder/myapp/.+$ /subfolder/myapp last;
```